# ng-bind-html not working in ng-repeat in angularjs code

Tags: angularjs

I am fetching html code from database and try to show it with angularjs on html page, when i print the code with `{{item}}` then it print html with tags but when i print the code with `<P ng-bind-html="item"></p>` then it show nothing
i also try `trustAsHtml` but it show same behavior too

here is the code

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rec.detail" >
 <span ng-bind-html="row.item"></span>
</div>
```

I expect the output only text not with html

Comment: What about using `ng-bind` only?

Comment: ng-bind show text with html tag

Answer (score 0):

I have link the `ngSanitize` module in my angular app and its start working
here is the link to module
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize